# Receiving signals from a PureScript Flame application

Tags: purescript

I'm experimenting to understand PureScript channels and signals better, and specifically their use with the UI library *Flame*.

I've created the following as a small example:

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)
import Flame (Html, QuerySelector(..))
import Flame.Application.NoEffects as FAN
import Flame.HTML.Attribute as HA
import Flame.HTML.Element as HE

data Message
  = ButtonOne
  | ButtonTwo

type Model
  = { buttonOneCount :: Int
    , buttonTwoCount :: Int
    }

init :: Model
init =
  { buttonOneCount: 0
  , buttonTwoCount: 0
  }

update :: Model -> Message -> Model
update model message = case message of
  ButtonOne -> model { buttonOneCount = model.buttonOneCount + 1 }
  ButtonTwo -> model { buttonTwoCount = model.buttonTwoCount + 1 }

view :: Model -> Html Message
view model =
  HE.main "main"
    [ HE.button [ HA.onClick ButtonOne ] "Button One"
    , HE.p_ ("button one: " <> show model.buttonOneCount)
    , HE.button [ HA.onClick ButtonTwo ] "Button Two"
    , HE.p_ ("button two: " <> show model.buttonTwoCount)
    ]

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  -- flameChannel :: Channel (Array Message)
  flameChannel <-
    FAN.mount (QuerySelector "main")
      { init, update, view }
  pure unit
```

I'm aware that any changes should be handled in `update` here, but as an experiment I'd like to subscribe to changes to `flameChannel` in `main` and run some code based on the `Message` Flame sends through that channel.

Just to get started, what could be added to make this output to the JavaScript console when the user clicks Button One or Button Two, using `flameChannel` in `main`?

I've tried playing around with various combinations of functions from `purescript-signal`: `subscribe`, `runSignal`, `get`, but got nowhere. I have also looked around at various games on GitHub that use the `purescript-signal` library, but they just seem to throw `runSignal` into the code, everything works and I don't understand why (also, those examples are a bit complex and far from what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok let's see - as you've already noticed you get a `Channel` (from signal) back that will notify you about `Message`s

you should now be able to use [`Signal.Channel.subscribe`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-signal/12.0.1/docs/Signal.Channel#v:subscribe) to turn this into a `Signal`

Now the way `Signal` works is that you should provide a `Signal` *signaling* `Effect`s (those will be executed/run) to `runSignal` - so you have to turn your `Signal (Array Message)` into a `Signal (Effect Unit)` first.

Luckily `Signal` is a `Functor` so you can use `map` or the provided `~>` (flipped `map`) to do this. I would suggest using [`flattenArray`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-signal/12.0.1/docs/Signal#v:flattenArray) first to make your life a bit easier:

```
logMessage :: Message -> Effect Unit
logMessage msg =
   case msg of
      ButtonOne -> log "button one"
      ButtonTwo -> log "button two"
```

and in `main`:

```
main = do
  flameChannel <-
    FAN.mount (QuerySelector "main")
      { init, update, view }
  let logSignal = 
    map logMessage $ flip flattenArray ButtonOne $ subscribe flameChannel
  runSignal logSignal
```

this should work

---

disclaimer: I did not try to compile this - if you get any issues please report and I'll see to it

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I feel like this must be close to the answer. Unfortunately my PureScript cannot find `(~>)`, which is weird, it should be in the Prelude? I tried using `map` but couldn't get it to work, would you mind either updating this to use `map` or tell me by what wizardry I can get PS to say something other than `Unknown operator` when it sees `~>`? Thanks! It's PS version 0.13.8 if that helps.

Comment: there is such an operator in prelude (but for nat. transormations) - the flipped map is from signal: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-signal/12.0.1/docs/Signal#v:(~%3E) - you can use map instead but you have to flip the arguments (it's `map f sig` instead of `sig ~> f`) - or ```sig `flip map` f` which is ugly

Comment: so with map it would be `let logSignal = map logMessage $ (subscribe flameChannel) # flattenArray` or so I think - maybe remove the `#` to be safe: `let logSignal = map logMessage $ flattenArray $ subscribe flameChannel`

Comment: I get a type error, it's misleading but I think it's because `flattenArray` is missing a parameter in the code above. It's type is `flattenArray :: forall a. Signal (Array a) -> a -> Signal a` (see it also takes an `a` as well as a `Signal (Array a)`)

Comment: The type error is: `Could not match type Signal Message with type Message` and `logMessage` is highlighted

Comment: yes sorry my bad - this parameter is a *seed* (you can get the "current value" from a signal and if there was nothing yet coming from the source signal this is used - the source signals seed is an empty array so that is useless to get an `a` that's why this is needded) - I'd suggest introducing some kind of NoOp-Message and using that (or changing to `Maybe a` and use `Nothing`)

Comment: For the purposes of this experiment/learning experience, I think it's fine to just send in a `ButtonOne` message as you've done in the answer, and for a proper project introduce a no-op message. Good suggestion! However, I think the params for `flattenArray` in the answer are backwards, it's type is: `flattenArray :: ∀ a. Signal (Array a) → a → Signal a` but the answer passes `a` as the first parameter.

Comment: jep you are right - not my day(s) it seems - thanks